# Bind DataTable to TextBox c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, data-binding, datatable

I have a multiline TextBox that i'd like to bind to a DataTable. But I want to customize the way the data is presented. I'm only going to want the column headers and the last row of data. And the format may go something like this:

```
Column1Title: RowNColumn1Value
Column2Title: RowNColumn2Value
```

And the columns may not be sequential. Perhaps i'll present column 3 and then column 5. I just want a way to be able specify it. How can all of this be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend using a different control for this.. perhaps a `DataGridView` or `DataGrid`, depending on if you are using WinForms or WPF, or some other technology.

Comment: is it possible to customize the way a datagridview is ordered?

Comment: Yes, you can either order the `DataSource` before binding, or you can allow the user to sort by column by clicking on the column header.  Or you can cook up your own custom sorting.. it is very flexible.